# chi square test for independence of variables with R

Tags: r, statistics

I have to make a chi square test of two physical variables with R. I'am trying with:

```
Library('MASS')
Library('gplots')
data<-read.table('data.dat',head=F) 
pp<-hist2d(data$V2,data$V3)
chisq.test(pp$counts)
```

but R says me:

```
Pearson's Chi-squared test

    data:  pp$counts 
    X-squared = NaN, df = 240, p-value = NA
```

I have used this script in past to performs chi square but now it does not work. where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hist2d` bins the data, but if some of the bins are always empty,
the chi squared statistic is not defined (because of a division by zero).
You can try to reduce the number of bins, 
or discard the bins that are empty.

```
library(gplots)
d <- data.frame( rnorm(100), rnorm(100) )

# Discard empty bins
p <- hist2d(d)
i <- apply( p$counts, 1, sum ) > 0
j <- apply( p$counts, 2, sum ) > 0
chisq.test( p$counts[i,j] )

# Reduce the number of bins
p <- hist2d(d,nbins=5)
chisq.test( p$counts )
```

(From a statistical point of view, 
I am not sure that what you are doing is optimal.)

Comment: If the data is already discrete (that is not clear from your question),
you do not need to call `hist2d`: 
`chisq.test(table(data[,2:3]))` should suffice.
If the data is continuous, by discretizing it, 
you actually discard information:
not only the precise value of the observations, 
but also their ordering.
If the suspected relation between the variables is
likely to be monotonic, you can use the correlation
(for linear relations)
or the rank correlation.
If the suspected relation between the variables 
is not monotonic or, even worse, if it is not
functional, that is trickier...

Comment: Here is an example of what can go wrong with continuous data,
when there are very few observations in each bin.
For two independent variables, the p-value is 0.23:
`d <- data.frame(runif(10),runif(10)); chisq.test(table(d))`.
For two dependent variables, the p-value is also 0.23
(we expect it to be different and close to 0):
`d <- data.frame(1:10,1:10); chisq.test(table(d))`.
There is, however, a warning, telling you that 
the test is unlikely to be valid.

Comment: you can `?cut` your data by `?quantile` or just cut it at useful breaks by looking at a `?hist` of your data. Then use `?table` to compare the two... then you can use `chisq.test(table(cut(x)),table(cut(y)))` and receive reasonable statistical results. It's important to look at your data though. Cells with a frequency less than 5 cause significance to be wonky (or at least innacurate).